# Styling MapBox GL Markers

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am trying to move from using Mapbox.js with Leaflet to Mapbox GL.

I have the following geojson that should be rendered as per the image attached. Unfortunately, after reading many articles and through the documentation related to data driven visualisation I've hit a wall. Wondered if anyone could help with an example?!

Here's the geojson:

```
{ "type":"Feature",geometry: { "type":"Point","coordinates":[1.1147,51.7829] },properties: { "title":"Paul","marker-color":"#0094F7","marker-size":"large","marker-symbol":"star" } },
{ "type":"Feature",geometry: { "type":"Point","coordinates":[-2.34851,52.6123] },properties: { "title":"Will","marker-color":"#F9883E","marker-size":"large","marker-symbol":"1" } },
{ "type":"Feature",geometry: { "type":"Point","coordinates":[-2.76389,53.0232] },properties: { "title":"Mark","marker-color":"#F1574E","marker-size":"large","marker-symbol":"13" } },
{ "type":"Feature",geometry: { "type":"Point","coordinates":[-.127211,51.6014] },properties: { "title":"David","marker-color":"#83C736","marker-size":"large","marker-symbol":"20" } },
{ "type":"Feature",geometry: { "type":"Point","coordinates":[-2.06682,53.4986] },properties: { "title":"Adam","marker-color":"#FC5C53","marker-size":"large","marker-symbol":"rocket" } }
```

The colour values are set by the end user and could be anything so I can't just create a lot of images to suit, and the numbers refer to dates so will be 1-31.

Here's what it currently looks like in Mapbox.js:[image: mapbox_markers]

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you found an easy way?

Comment: Answer below worked. Have to iterate over each point with your styles HTML element. Wouldn’t recommend doing it on a large number of points but worked for my use case.

Answer (score 4):

Using [Markers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#Marker), you have full control to display any HTML element you like - so you could use CSS to construct a circle or teardrop of the right color, or an SVG icon.

See this example: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/custom-marker-icons/

Essentially, instead of adding the GeoJSON directly as a source *into* the map, you will want to iterate over each point, and add markers *onto* the map.

Comment: One thing to add for people who still looking for a way for simple creation of makers like on attached picture: current version of Mapbox GL js (0.51.1) unfortuantely does not support creation of markers with any symbols except a circle(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/marker-from-geocode/) inside "tear" out of the box.